# SharePoint sites are down for few minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration, sharepoint-farm, sharepoint-administration

All the sites are down eventually and showing 504 error or buffering for few minutes. And Then back within 10 minutes or if I want quickly I restart the Web Server from IIS Manager, and after restart all content are showing. Can anyone help me that why SharePoint behave like this? Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> The 504 Gateway error is usually temporary, and different reasons may
> cause it. Most often than not, the problem is due to a client-end
> issue like Internet connection troubles.
>
> However, the hitch may be due to server-to-server network connectivity
> issues or a server being down. For example, when a server is under
> maintenance, you would likely see the 504 error on a website hosted
> there. Once this process is completed, the site should become
> accessible again.
>
> Although this is usually a server-side error, there is a possibility
> that the issue is on your end. If you see this error while visiting
> your favorite website, there are a few quick checks you can try to
> determine whether that is the case. Other culprits for an HTTP 504
> error may be a traffic overload on the server, bugs in the code of a
> website, or DNS issues.
>
> Additionally, this error can be due to other services acting like
> proxy servers for a website – CDN services, API gateways, etc.

You can try these method:

Restart your network devices

Flush your computer’s DNS cache

For more information, please refer to:

https://world.siteground.com/kb/504-gateway-timeout/
https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/504-gateway-timeout-how-to-fix-it/